# Переменная в os.system

Tags: python

Есть команда, которая озвучивает текст:

`echo "Текст" | RHVoice-test -p anna -v 200 -o - 2>/dev/null | aplay - 2>/dev/null`

Для питона конструкция будет выглядеть так:

`os.system('echo "Текст" | RHVoice-test -p anna -v 200 -o - 2>/dev/null | aplay - 2>/dev/null')`

Но как в этом случае я могу подставить переменную вместо "Текст" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как всегда:

```
import os
txt = "Text"
os.system(f'echo "{txt}" | RHVoice-test -p anna -v 200 -o - 2>/dev/null | aplay - 2>/dev/null')
```